# Modifying the color of grep

Tags: command-line, grep

When I grep something, the result is always in red. I know that the command `grep --color` prints the result in color, which by default is red. Can I change the color?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can change the highlight color of `grep` by using an environment variable, `GREP_COLORS`, which you can set like this:

```bsh
export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31'
```

---

## Numeric options

The numbers can style text, change the foreground color or the background color, or change fonts.

The starting conditions for all `GREP_COLORS` options are the terminal's default text style, font, and colors. Resetting any of these will revert to the terminal's defaults, not any of `grep`'s defaults.

#### Legend

- `ᴀ;ʙ;…` — `;` separates numeric options that you want to combine (e.g., bold yellow-on-black text combines options `1`, `33`, and `40` into `1;33;40`)
- `+ᴇꜰꜰᴇᴄᴛ` — *ᴇꜰꜰᴇᴄᴛ* gets turned on when you use that numeric option
- `-ᴇꜰꜰᴇᴄᴛ` — *ᴇꜰꜰᴇᴄᴛ* gets turned off when you use that numeric option
- `color`, `green`, `cyan`, and `grey` — in the "Text styling" section, these refer to the foreground color
- `colors` — in the "Text styling" section, this refers to both the foreground color and the background color
- `this color` — in the "Foreground colors" section, this refers to the foreground color; in the "Background colors" section, this refers to the background color

#### Text styling

An empty string or `0` resets all text styling and resets both colors to the defaults but **does not** reset the font to the default.

```
┏━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ ### ┃ GNOME Terminal          ┃ xterm                   ┃ non-GUI TTY           ┃
┡━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│     │ «reset style+colors»    │ «reset style+colors»    │ «reset style+colors»  │
│   0 │ «reset style+colors»    │ «reset style+colors»    │ «reset style+colors»  │
├─────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│   1 │ +bold, +brighter color  │ +bold, +brighter color  │ +brighter color,      │
│     │                         │                         │   -forced grey        │
│   2 │ +fainter color          │ +fainter color          │ +forced grey          │
│   3 │ +italic                 │ +italic                 │ +forced green         │
│     │                         │                         │   ● overrides 2 and 4 │
│   4 │ +underline              │ +underline              │ +forced cyan          │
│     │                         │                         │   ● overrides 2       │
│   5 │ «no effect»             │ +blink                  │ «no effect»           │
│   7 │ +invert colors          │ +invert colors          │ +invert colors        │
│   8 │ +invisible              │ +invisible              │ «no effect»           │
│     │                         │   ● underline appears   │                       │
│   9 │ +strikethrough          │ +strikethrough          │ «no effect»           │
├─────┼─────────────────────────┤                         ├───────────────────────┤
│  21 │ -bold, -brighter color, │ +double underline       │ -brighter color,      │
│     │   -fainter color        ├─────────────────────────┤   -forced grey        │
│  22 │ -bold, -brighter color, │ -bold, -brighter color, │ -brighter color,      │
│     │   -fainter color        │   -fainter color        │   -forced grey        │
│  23 │ -italic                 │ -italic                 │ -forced green         │
│  24 │ -underline              │ -underline,             │ -forced cyan          │
│     │                         │   -double underline     │                       │
│  25 │ «no effect»             │ -blink                  │ «no effect»           │
│  27 │ -invert colors          │ -invert colors          │ -invert colors        │
│  28 │ -invisible              │ -invisible              │ «no effect»           │
│  29 │ -strikethrough          │ -strikethrough          │ «no effect»           │
└─────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

#### Foreground colors

```
┏━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ ### ┃ GNOME Terminal          ┃ xterm                   ┃ non-GUI TTY           ┃
┡━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│  39 │ «reset this color»      │ «reset this color»      │ «reset this color»    │
├─────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│  30 │ very dark grey          │ black                   │ black                 │
│  31 │ dull red                │ red                     │ light red             │
│  32 │ dull green              │ light green             │ light green           │
│  33 │ dull yellow             │ yellow                  │ yellow                │
│  34 │ greyish blue            │ dark blue               │ sky blue              │
│  35 │ dull purple             │ purple                  │ purple                │
│  36 │ teal                    │ cyan                    │ cyan                  │
│  37 │ light grey              │ light grey              │ light grey            │
├─────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│  90 │ dark grey               │ dull grey               │ dull grey             │
│  91 │ red                     │ bright red              │ bright red            │
│  92 │ lime green              │ bright green            │ bright green          │
│  93 │ yellow                  │ bright yellow           │ pure yellow           │
│  94 │ light greyish blue      │ dull blue               │ deep blue             │
│  95 │ light purple            │ magenta                 │ magenta               │
│  96 │ cyan                    │ bright cyan             │ bright cyan           │
│  97 │ off white               │ white                   │ white                 │
├─────┴──────┬──────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┤
│ 38;2;ʀ;ɢ;ʙ │ replace ʀ, ɢ, and ʙ with RGB values from 0 to 255                  │
│            │   for closest supported color (non-GUI TTY has only 16 colors!)    │
│ 38;5;ɴ     │ replace ɴ with value from 256-color chart below                    │
│            │   for closest supported color (non-GUI TTY has only 16 colors!)    │
└────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

#### Background colors

Note that the non-GUI TTY doesn't provide a brighter background color series.

```
┏━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ ### ┃ GNOME Terminal          ┃ xterm                   ┃ non-GUI TTY           ┃
┡━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│  49 │ «reset this color»      │ «reset this color»      │ «reset this color»    │
├─────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│  40 │ very dark grey          │ black                   │ black                 │
│  41 │ dull red                │ red                     │ light red             │
│  42 │ dull green              │ light green             │ light green           │
│  43 │ dull yellow             │ yellow                  │ yellow                │
│  44 │ greyish blue            │ dark blue               │ sky blue              │
│  45 │ dull purple             │ purple                  │ purple                │
│  46 │ teal                    │ cyan                    │ cyan                  │
│  47 │ light grey              │ light grey              │ light grey            │
├─────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────┼╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶┤
│ 100 │ dark grey               │ dull grey               │ black                 │
│ 101 │ red                     │ bright red              │ light red             │
│ 102 │ lime green              │ bright green            │ light green           │
│ 103 │ yellow                  │ bright yellow           │ yellow                │
│ 104 │ light greyish blue      │ dull blue               │ sky blue              │
│ 105 │ light purple            │ magenta                 │ purple                │
│ 106 │ cyan                    │ bright cyan             │ cyan                  │
│ 107 │ off white               │ white                   │ light grey            │
├─────┴──────┬──────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┤
│ 48;2;ʀ;ɢ;ʙ │ replace ʀ, ɢ, and ʙ with RGB values from 0 to 255                  │
│            │   for closest supported color (non-GUI TTY has only 8 colors!)     │
│ 48;5;ɴ     │ replace ɴ with value from 256-color chart below                    │
│            │   for closest supported color (non-GUI TTY has only 8 colors!)     │
└────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

#### 256-color chart

> [image: 256-color chart]
>
> <sup><sup>Above chart is a screenshot of content published in ["ANSI escape code, 8-bit colors" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit), authored [by CMG Lee et al. on 24 February 2016 and later](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ANSI_escape_code&diff=706645748&oldid=706104066), and [licensed by the authors](https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use/en#7._Licensing_of_Content) under both [the CC BY-SA 3.0 copyright license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and [the GFDL copyright license](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html).</sup></sup>

Colors from the 256-color chart above can be used as follows:

- `38;5;ɴ` — replace ɴ with the value of a particular color in the chart above to change the **foreground color** to the closest color the terminal supports
- `48;5;ɴ` — replace ɴ with the value of a particular color in the chart above to change the **background color** to the closest color the terminal supports

For example, `38;5;214;48;5;30` will set the foreground to color `214` and the background to color `30`, giving an orange-on-teal result on terminals that support it.

Note that not all terminals support all 256 colors, so it's important to realize that the chosen color might not be used. Only the supported color closest to the one chosen will be used.

For example, the non-GUI TTY only supports the basic 16 colors for foreground and the basic 8 colors for background, so the closest colors that end up being used may not be what you expect. As an example, the orange-on-teal selection above (`38;5;214;48;5;30`) shows as yellow-on-black in the non-GUI TTY, since those are the closest supported colors.

#### Fonts

`10` is the default font. `11` through `20` are potential alternate fonts  (`20` usually means [a  font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) in the rare terminals that support it). Only `10` and `12` seem to exist by default in the non-GUI TTY, and none exist in GNOME Terminal or `xterm`.

`grep` doesn't properly switch fonts back before exiting, so run `reset` if you get stuck in an unwanted font after `grep` returns to the shell.

```
┏━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ ### ┃ GNOME Terminal          ┃ xterm                   ┃ non-GUI TTY           ┃
┡━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│  10 │ «no effect»             │ «no effect»             │ «reset font»          │
│  11 │ «no effect»             │ «no effect»             │ -messed up font       │
│  12 │ «no effect»             │ «no effect»             │ +messed up font       │
└─────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

> <sup>"Numeric options" section sources:</sup>
>           <sup>● ["ANSI escape code, SGR (Select Graphic Rendition) parameters" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters)</sup>
>           <sup>● Experimental verification on GNOME Terminal, `xterm`, and non-GUI-mode TTY on Ubuntu 16.04</sup>

---

[image: examples of color changes after setting <code>GREP_COLORS</code>]

The default value of `GREP_COLORS` is `'ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'`

The meaning of every element accepted on `GREP_COLORS` can be checked at [GNU.org's manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-GREP_005fCOLORS-environment-variable).

For completion, and as pointed out by @damadam, you need to add the `export` to your `.bashrc` in order to save the changes.

**Related:**

[Multicolored Grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104350/multicolored-grep)

[Use different colors for every another grep](https://superuser.com/questions/676228/use-different-colors-for-every-another-grep)

Comment: There are **much** more colors and formatting options available, try `<<<hello GREP_COLORS='ms=5;104' grep '.*'` once! A list of codes can be found e.g. [here](http://leocharre.com/articles/setting-ls_colors-colors-of-directory-listings-in-bash-terminal/) (section 6).

Comment: How do you use color values from the 256 color table with GREP_COLORS?

Comment: @SebastianStark For foreground, use `38;5;ɴ`, where ɴ should be replaced with one of the color values. For background, use `48;5;ɴ` in the same way. For example, `38;5;214;48;5;30` should give you orange on teal. If it doesn't, your terminal might not support 256 colors. For example, the non-GUI TTY only supports 16 colors for foreground and 8 for background and will pick the foreground and background colors out of those 16 and 8 closest to orange on teal, which is yellow on black.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex thx, works just fine. It's not very obvious from the answer though.

Comment: @SebastianStark I've changed the description of the RGB and 256-color parameters. Do you think they're better now?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex thanks, though for me the problem was more that in the "256 color" section of the text there's no mentioning of those options, just the color table

Comment: @SebastianStark Ahh, I see. I'll add a short blurb. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Comment: And of course the latest apple macbook coolaid bash product is different; To get your example to work I had to change it: `export GREP_COLOR=32; ls | grep hello`.  Then it colors the hello in a green color.

Comment: This could be the best ever stack exchange answer.

Comment: Thanks for the complete info for ANSI colors. Could be a good Wiki for generations.

Answer (score 6):

In addition of the answer from @M. Becerra, don't forget to add this `export` inside `~/.bashrc`. You can do it like that:

```sh
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and type now your `export`:

```sh
export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;33:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'
```

This sets `grep` results to yellow, and I don't need to redo the `export` after restart terminal or the computer.

Comment: edit the original answer to make it better next time.

Comment: This is nicer BUT it only seems to work on Linux, not Mac :(

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Mac is really different from Ubuntu, Mac isn't Linux, and I do this step for Ubuntu (if it was for Mac, it would be off-topic here, Mac questions must be asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yeah. It's not worth me posting another question just for me to show my sadness though :)

Comment: how should the command be written to work in Android mksh shell?

Answer (score 1):

Select Graphic Rendition (SGR) commands are interpreted by the terminal or terminal emulator. Answer initiated by M. Becerra (above) goes into SGR values.

The environment variable `GREP_COLORS` is just like `LS_COLORS` except...

| Code | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `mt` | SGR for `ms` and `mc`. |
| `ms` | SGR for non-matching context in line with match. |
| `mc` | SGR for non-matching context in line with match (`-v`). |
| `sl` | SGR for whole selected lines. |
| `cx` | SGR for whole context lines. |
| `rv` | boolean that reverses `sl` and `cx`. |
| `fn` | SGR for file names (`-H`). |
| `ln` | SGR for line numbers (`-n`). |
| `bn` | SGR for byte offsets. |
| `se` | SGR for separators between line and context fields (`:` and `-`). |
| `ne` | boolean to prevent clearing to eol. |

Note: Omitting a boolean sets the value to false.

```bash
export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;33:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=1;96:ln=1;96:bn=1;96:se=1;97'
```

The yellow from damadam was good, but I needed to be able to see the filenames against a black background.

This information is actually in the grep man pages (@see man grep).