# Combining ANSI Color codes -- Foreground and background color merging

Tags: command-line, zsh

I have this function in zsh to run `grep` on the output of `git log` to highlight the line with the commit's hash, author, message, etc.. I'm rewriting to try and add color to the output and want to prevent grep from overwriting the foreground color that's passed. 
I've tried all variations of `--color=(always|never|auto)`. This is the current command I'm stuck with:

```
# raw command:
unbuffer git log --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) \t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(white)%s%C(reset)' | grep -i '.*'update'.*' | column -t -s $'\t'

# w/ comments:
unbuffer # From `expect` apt package, preserves color across piping by pushing to a buffer? idk.

# git log, formatted
git log --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) \t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(white)%s%C(reset)'

grep -i '.*'update'.*' # grep `update` from any line in input, hardcoded here but could also be a parameter

column -t -s $'\t' # tabulate
```

The output looks like this.

[image: The output looks like this]

In addition, piping to `column` to tabulate the output without the use of `unbuffer` also washes away the color and there's no `--color=never` option for the `column` command. The use of `unbuffer` also causes `grep`'s coloring to not work at all.

What I want is to just have the background of the grep match to be highlighted red, green, or whatever color while preserving the color of the text as seen in the image, i.e. green on red, blue on red, etc. I'm not completely familiar with how terminals work under the hood and why color is lost when piping.

I'm sure I could write a C++ program to do all this by inserting ANSI color codes where necessary but I figured I would at least ask. I do want to only use commands that can be installed via `apt` as this is a part of my whole terminal config that I sync across multiple devices via a git repo..

Edits below this point:

- I originally tried to include a `-A1 -B1` flag with `grep` to show the commit before and after, hence the desire for explicit highlighting.
- The answer from [@daniel-t](https://askubuntu.com/users/1004020/daniel-t) works for resolving coloring being lost by `git log`, but disables `grep` from highlighting matches.

I am able to achieve the desired effect by writing color codes manually into a string and echoing via `echo "\e[1;34m13ca348\e[m \e[1;36mSun, 29 Jan\e[m -- \e[1;41m\e[1;32mCommit message\e[m"`. This output is exactly what I'm looking for (notice the green on red from wrapping the foreground and background color codes) but I doubt terminal programs structure colors this way so I don't know if another program would be able combine them easily this way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Last solution

Try `git log --color --pretty="$(printf '\e[1;34m%%h \e[36m%%aD\e[35G\e[;2;37m\t%%an\e[70G\e[;37m%%s\e[m')" | GREP_COLORS='ms=1;32;41:sl=37' grep -Pi '\e\[;37m.*\K''update' --color=always`. I eliminated the use of `column` and `sed`. The new `\e[70G` just moves the cursor to column 70, and that should be enough for names. The first two columns are more or less fixed-length and don't need much.

[image: last solution]

## Simple solution

Try `git log --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) \t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(bold green red)%s%C(reset)' --color=always | grep -i '.*'update'.*' | column -t -s $'\t'`. I just changed the last "white" to "bold green red".

[image: highlight entire commit message]

Based on your desired color code example highlighting the entire commit message, it was easy to color the entire last column. There is no need for combining colors from two commands. I don't know which version of grep you are using that has red as the background, but the grep on Ubuntu has red as the foreground, so we needed to override this.

## Advanced solution

EDIT: Based on what you seem to want:

The command becomes `git log --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) \t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(white)%s%C(reset)' --color=always | GREP_COLORS='ms=1;41;32:sl=37' grep -Pi '\e\[37m.*\K''update' --color=always | column -t -s $'\t'`. Edit the `'update'` part to choose which pattern to search for.

[image: highlight only matched part]

The `GREP_COLORS` environment variable controls how grep highlights and is separated by `:`. `ms=1;32;41` applies bold green on red, respectively. grep will reset the colors immediately after, so we need to add `sl=37` to get back the white (necessary on xterm but not most terminals like Konsole). ANSI color escape sequences would normally merge with the previous foreground, background, or style if omitted, but you can't push/pop/undo so that doesn't work for your case. I then match for `\e\[37m` (requires `-P`) to restrict us to the commit message (to avoid glitchy colors in case it matches elsewhere), relying on the fact that we only use white in git once. Then the `.*\K` tells grep to search for your keyword after, and to avoid highlighting and ruining the previous color code itself. Finally we need `--color=always` to enable our new colors.

By the way, you don't need to use reset so much. Here is a shorter version `git log --color --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h \t%C(cyan)%aD\t%C(reset dim white)\t%an\t%C(reset white)%s%C(reset)' | GREP_COLORS='ms=1;32;41:sl=37' grep -Pi '\e\[;37m.*\K''update' --color=always | column -t -s $'\t'`. The middle ones are still there because they are more reliable than no-dim (same color code outputted as no-bold), and the last one is only needed if you don't have a colored bash prompt.

## Old answer

You need to pass `--color=always` to `git`, not `grep` or `column`. Try `git log --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) \t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(white)%s%C(reset)' --color=always | grep -i '.*'update'.*' | column -t -s $'\t'`.

I get the following output:

```
home@daniel-tablet1:~/WebstormProjects/linuxenv$ git log --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) \t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(white)%s%C(reset)' --color=always | grep -i '.*'update'.*' | column -t -s $'\t'
13ca348   Sun, 29 Jan 2023 15:56:02 -0500    Daniel Tang  Update PlantUML 1.2022.6 -> 1.2023.0
83b31a2   Sun, 29 Jan 2023 15:48:21 -0500    Daniel Tang  Update Gradle 7.5.1 -> 7.6
85f2b04   Sun, 29 Jan 2023 15:45:28 -0500    Daniel Tang  Update GraalVM 22.3.0 -> 22.3.1
5e86df9   Sun, 29 Jan 2023 15:39:59 -0500    Daniel Tang  Update JetBrainsMono 2.242 -> 2.304
7e984d4   Wed, 26 Oct 2022 18:21:23 -0400    Daniel Tang  Update graalvm 22.3
ee202a6   Wed, 12 Oct 2022 10:00:33 -0400    Daniel Tang  Update rustup settings.toml hash
6a0c58f   Mon, 19 Sep 2022 23:54:54 -0400    Daniel Tang  Update
a9755a3   Tue, 23 Mar 2021 13:54:27 -0400    Daniel Tang  Fix nvmupdate
e936dab   Fri, 19 Mar 2021 17:29:32 -0400    Daniel Tang  Update
0b8e7e3   Wed, 17 Mar 2021 04:19:11 -0400    Daniel Tang  Update
(sky blue)(turquoise                    )    (dark grey)  (white) (konsole)
(RGB blue)(cyan                         )    (dark grey)  (light gray) (xterm)
(navyblue)(aquamarine                   )    (dark grey)  (light gray) (gnome-terminal)
```

I removed `unbuffer` because it not only needed to be installed, but also causes the command to hang on my computer. The standard command for what you desire is `stdbuf -o0`. If you say that `unbuffer` was fixing the colors, that must be because it was pretending to be a terminal by allocating a PTY. That is unnecessary if we use the more efficient direct solution of `--color=always`.

If you wanted to find out which command was failing to pass on the color, you can use `cat`. `git log --pretty=$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) \t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(white)%s%C(reset)' | cat` results in missing color, and without the `cat` there is paging and color. This shows that it's `git` that fails to emit the ANSI color codes. Even if you wrote a C++ program, those are your own color code, and no color codes from `git`.

Don't worry about `grep` overwriting your color code. Your `.*'update'.*` goes to the start of the line. A color code is specially chosen text with escape sequences. Even if grep appended any color codes, it will be overwritten by `git`'s color code immediately after. The `head -n1` output of the `git --color=always` is `\e[1;34m9a8c818\e[m \t\e[1;36mMon`. In this case, it's good that `grep` did not decided to insert color codes because it was pipe to something, namely `column` after, but even if you gave `grep` `--color=always`, it just prepends it color codes. I get `\e[01;31m\e[K\e[1;34m13ca348\e[m \t\e[1;36mSun, 29 Jan`. It appears the same visually because the `grep`'s colors are immediately overwritten by `git`'s colors from earlier.

Comment: It's common for many commands to not include non printing escape sequences when a pipe is detected (as those might cause parsing/processing issues.) ... Not only `grep` in this situation but also `git` as it seems which could be the root cause for the issue in OP.

Comment: This resolves the color loss, but does not achieve the desired effect of explicit background-highlighting. I edited the original post with additional info.

Comment: @Sargates I was able to find a solution that eliminates the `column_ansi` and `sed`

Comment: Your command doesn't work for me. Using the native `column` washes the "dim white" (grey) after the `column` call, every other color remains, which is why I looked for an alternative tabulator. I found other people talking about issues with color being removed from piping `column`. Which is why I found `column_ansi`. The `sed` call is also an artifact of calling `column_ansi` it seems to have a trailing newline which doesn't happen with native `column`. That's what the `sed` call was for.
It seems we reached the same solution.

Comment: Also, I work on WSL in Windows Terminal. So I assume there's some external reason as to why the native `column` wasn't working for me but seems to have worked for you. I was still able to reach a solution so thanks for the help.

Comment: This is why I chose to remove `column` and replace it with `\e[70G`, which should be faster and more consistent. But also thank you for showing me the `GREP_COLORS` part!

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to find a solution. Setting `GREP_COLORS` inline with the `grep` call allowed me to change grep to only highlight the background without conflicting with the foreground coloring from `git log`. I also had to pass `--color=always` in `grep` to prevent washing when piped to `column` like so: `GREP_COLORS="ms=41" grep -i update --color=always`

> See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1485711/1764786 for a table on `GREP_COLORS` placeholders

Also the issue with `column` is that it doesn't support every ANSI color escape and ends up washing any it doesn't like. My fix for this was to use [`column_ansi`](https://github.com/LukeSavefrogs/column_ansi) and that acts as a drop-in replacement (mostly).

Like I said in the edit, I was trying to include the flags `-A1 -B1` in `grep` to get the commit before and after.

Here is the full command I ended up using and I ended up wrapping it in a function:

```
glgrep() {
    git log --color=always --pretty=format:$'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset)\t%C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset)\t%C(dim white)\t%an%C(reset)\t%C(white)%s%C(reset)' | GREP_COLORS="ms=41" grep -i $1 --color=always -A1 -B1 | column_ansi -t -s $'\t' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'
    # call after `column_ansi` requires trimming. i dont know why (extra following newline char?)
}
```

Comment: The "format:" in "--pretty=format" is not recommended because it might eat the final newline. It's better to specify "tformat" instead or leave it out to automatically do so.