# changing grep command --color from red to another color

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, colors, alias

I'm searching from the file using grep command with particular pattern,
`sysadmin@localhost:~$ grep bash /etc/passwd`

which return the output like below
`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash                                                  operator:x:1000:37::/root:/bin/bash                                              sysadmin:x:1001:1001:System Administrator,,,,:/home/sysadmin:/bin/bash`

How can I change the default color of red to something different (eg.blue)

Comment: The answer is `export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;34'`. Does this answer your question? [Modifying the color of grep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042234/modifying-the-color-of-grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution:

Add `--color=always` to the grep options... then pipe the result into
`| sed -re 's/31m/32m/'` and you will get green text instead of the red.

**Another way is described in the man page:**
`$ man grep`, then
type `/_COLOR` hit enter, hit `n` once
*(alternatively type `/^ +GREP_COLOR$`and hit enter)*

Comment: Note: the `31m` is part of an ESC or CSI-sequence defined by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Hmm... The interesting portion the wikipedia page is at. "Select Graphic Rendition"

Comment: If your input was `bob31man:x:1000:37::/root:/bin/bash` that'd change `bob31man` to `bob32man` and leave `bash` highlighted in red.

Comment: Yes, and that would be a "not covered" case, as is often the case with the simplest form of `sed` use. You have to weight the simplicity against the usefulness.